# How to upload zip attachment to issue using REST API?

Tags: jira-rest-api

i'm trying now to upload zip attachment through REST API but no success. It works, when I'm trying to attach picture, but when I use the same command for zip

> curl -D- -u Bogdan:Password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck"
>   -F "file=@xla-snapshot.zip" `http://localhost:5555/rest/api/2/issue/XA-1/attachments`

I have such response:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   X-AREQUESTID: 1352x1015x1 X-ASEN: SEN-2117746 Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=97A763E5E09F7F8476CEDF07A2ACD7C6; Path=/; HttpOnly
>   X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK Set-Cookie:
>   atlassian.xsrf.token=B7X0-QLNV-RIK8-C6T9|aca131a97f4fdb61cebd0bfb6681c66824d62464|lin;
>   Path=/ X-ASESSIONID: nzll4r X-AUSERNAME: Bogdan Cache-Control:
>   no-cache, no-store, no-transform X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 21:32:11 GMT

When I modified and explicitly said content type that it is zip

> url -D- -u Bogdan:Password -X POST -H "Content-Type:
>   application/zip" -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F
>   "file=@xla-snapshot.zip"
>   `http://localhost:5555/rest/api/2/issue/XA-1/attachments`

I got an "Unsupported Media Type" response:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Server:
>   Apache-Coyote/1.1 X-AREQUESTID: 1353x1016x1 X-ASEN: SEN-2117746
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6225FF25F6D71BADB6890C9F448608B6; Path=/;
>   HttpOnly X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK Set-Cookie:
>   atlassian.xsrf.token=B7X0-QLNV-RIK8-C6T9|e2c7fc222c74c37f5080150df1cd865eaa8daf7e|lin;
>   Path=/ X-ASESSIONID: 1lbjx70 X-AUSERNAME: Bogdan
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   Content-Language: en Content-Length: 1092 Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014
>   21:33:07 GMT

Is it possible actually to upload archives via REST Api?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that the file was too big for download, the limit is 10 Mb, and I was trying to upload more than it.

Quite sad that looking at this documentation `https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4527` there is no information about 404, when it can happen. And no information how you can guess the real cause